# quotes in vb.net links

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a link from what the user filepath that is given from an openfiledialog. But I can't get all the quotes in the right places

```
   DOCTextBox.Text = "<a href=" & OpenFileDialog1.FileName &  "target=_"blank">" & TitleTextBox.Text & "</a>"
```

Comment: @SLaks - Watch your language, man. No need for name calling. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DOCTextBox.Text = "<a href=""" & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & """ target=_""blank"">" & TitleTextBox.Text & "</a>"
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to put a `"` in a VB.Net string literal, you need to write `""`.

For example:

```
   "<a href=""" & HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) _
 & """target=_""blank"">" & HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(TitleTextBox.Text) & "</a>"
```

Comment: """target=_"""blank""">" ruins it

Comment: @New: Yes; I meant to put two quotes there, not three.  Fixed.

Comment: Three quotes are used to make a string that starts with a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to add quotes into the final string produced from the expression.  In order to do that use a pair of double quotes `""`.  For example

```
"<a href=""" & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & """></a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use triple quotes such as `"""`